# MATLAB NaN Replacement

Tags: matlab, correlation

I am getting NaNs when I use perform correlation between two matrices, but I want to ignore them, and I read on some MATLAB forum that replacing NaNs with the means obtained by nanmean is a pretty good replacement. So I executed the following code, but Im still getting NaNs in my result. Why is that happening?

```
cor1nan=nanmean(correlations1);
mod1cor=isnan(correlations1);

for z=1:264
for a=1:264

 if(mod1cor(a,z)==1)
     correlations1(a,z)=cor1nan(z);
 end
 end
 end
```

Just noticed that some of the values in cor1nan are NaNs themselves.. how I go about solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have columns that are all `NaN`, then `nanmean` will keep it as `NaN` if I read it correctly.  Then your loop below will substitute in a `NaN`, thus keeping them.

A suggestion for how to solve it is as follows.  Replace your code with:

```
  cor1nan=nanmean(correlations1);
  corAllnan = nanmean(cor1nan);
  cor1nan(isnan(cor1nan)) = corAllmean;
  mod1cor = isnan(correlations1);

  for z = 1:size(correlations1,2),
         correlations1(isnan(correlations1(:,z)),z) = cor1nan(z);
  end
```

This will replace the `NaN`s in `cor1nan` with the mean of the non-`NaN` values in `cor1nan`

Comment: Was that the problem?  I'm posting a solution to it above.

Comment: No I want to know how to remove the NaNs, without the results getting affected too much?

Comment: Thank you - so you are performing the nanmean two times. You could tell me how to execute the loops more efficiently..Im new to MATLAB.

Comment: Edited it.  You should break apart what I did piece by piece to understand it.